# Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) loginPopup doesn't properly close itself

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I'm not getting loginResponse from loginPopup(requestObj) of UserAgentApplication instance using MSAL library.

Azure sample works as SPA from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-graphapi-v2/blob/quickstart/JavaScriptSPA/index.html. It's not working when we integrate this in our simple javascript plugin.

```
let loginPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(MSAL_CONFIG);

    myMSALObj.loginPopup(TOKEN_REQUEST).then(function(idToken){
                acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
                resolve();
              }).catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
                reject();
              });

    return loginPromise;

}
```

Expected behavior:
A login popup pops up and after the user logs in the pop up closes itself and the loginPopup promise resolves (or rejects).

Actual behavior:
A login popup pops up and after the user logs in the pop up redirects back to my site in the pop up.

Comment: Any update on this one?

Comment: I think this is a problem again with MSAL.js version 1.4.8 also. In my case, I'm working on a SharePoint Add-in and it looks like setting my RedirectURI to https://[myTenantName]-[myAddinAppHash].sharepoint.com allows the popup to close properly and let me grab an ID Token.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this issue as well, and it was resolved upon updating the code to utilize MSAL.js version 1.2.0.

Here is the release information: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/MSAL-JS-1.2.X